# Ruby on Rails - Saving with Multiselect

Tags: ruby-on-rails, select

I am trying to learn RoR by writing a simple program, but am getting stuck with saving form data from a multi select.  Can someone please help me understand multi select options in Rails.  I have a form with a multi select of different board games.  I want to save the selected game ids into a table as "2,3".  However, currently it is saving it as: game_id: "[\"\", \"2\", \"3\"]"

I tried using a join before saving to the database:

```
self.game_id = game_id.join(', ')
```

but get the following error: NoMethodError (undefined method `join' for "[\"\", \"3\", \"4\"]":String):

I have the params setup as:

```
def setup_params
  params.require(:user).permit(:game_id => [])
end
```

and the view as:

```
  <%= f.label :game_id, "Board Games" %>
  <%= f.select(:game_id, @game.map {|g| [g.game_name, g.id]}, {}, {:multiple => true}) %>
```

From the error, it seems like it gets returned as a string? Also, I'm not sure why it has the initial blank in the array.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I think you've to remove the blank value from the array.

```
self.game_id = game_id.reject(&:empty?).map { |t| t }.join(", ")
```

this may help you!